# <a> doesn't link to external links including ids from internet explorer

Tags: html, browser, hyperlink

I'm playing around with basic HTML and came up with some strange behavior of my browser

I'm using Internet Explorer 10, Chrome 26.something and Firefox 20.0.1

When I click the  element with the external link of href = http://wickedlysmart.com/buzz/index.html#Coffee,
it wouldn't jump to the id, just show the webpage from its top - as if i didn't added the "#Coffee" id name (it only happens on IE, the other browsers are jumping to the tag with the id "Coffee", although there is an `<h2>` with that id (this site isn't local)

but when I create a new html page, a local one - all of the 3 browsers are acting normal and jump to the element in that page with the id coming right after the '#'.

Any thoughts ?

p.s. I can't edit the external page who's link I'm using (that is the point of the exercise), furthermore - I've tried it with an anchor in a wikipedia page, might it be something local for just me ?

Comment: Very odd, IE9 is jumping to that anchor for me. I don't have 10 installed but that's what it should do.

Comment: Are you sure? IE10 is working just fine for me.

Comment: IE 7 (Win XP) is jumping straight to that element.

Answer (score 1):

Add the name-Attribute to the element:

```
<h3 id="Coffee" name="Coffee">Coffee</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't cut it here - as I've added in the p.s. after reading your answer - I can't manipulate the external webpage.